# Why can I not use type assignment when consuming an interface with an extended generic and default type?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99#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-CABYVKpPA0HqiGhIA)

I want to be able to consume implementations of the `Getter` interface and either specify the return type in a generic or describe the return type in standard type assignment. In both cases, the type needs to look like a simple object, so I am extending a `Record` to encourage compiler errors when the type doesn't match (like `number`, or `string`).

When no type is supplied, assume it's an untyped simple object.

Currently, it fails stating that:

```
Property 'bar' is missing in type 'Record<string, any>' but required in type 'Foo'.
```

However `Foo` is a "simple" object

```
type SimpleObject = Record<string, any>

interface Getter<T extends SimpleObject = SimpleObject> {
  getBody(): T
}

type Foo = {
  bar: string
}

// Case 1: Assume a simple object when no type information is supplied
void function () {
  const getter: Getter = {} as any

  const value = getter.getBody()
}

// Case 2: Use generic parameter to assign type when specified
void function() {
  const getter: Getter<Foo> = {} as any

  const value = getter.getBody()
}

// Case 3: Use type assignment, but validate that the type is a "simple object"
void function() {
  const getter: Getter = {} as any

  // Fails
  const value: Foo = getter.getBody()
}
```

Comment: You're asking why `SimpleObject` is not assignable to `Foo`? Because it doesn't have `bar` property (as the error suggests)

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgWzAGwgeQEYCsIGNhQC8UASngPYBOAJgDwDOwlcAdgOYA0UAhiyAHwAoQa2ARKAM265oAcQjAxlWgBUoEAB5iW1erEQp02PAWLwkqTDnz8oAb0FQobBQCFy1EKoCMRKCv4ACgBKAC5-b0EAX2FQSCgAMXJyPwcnDG5KcMZmdmjhAHoCqABhbnpob3CAQXp6AFcEaG4oegNUKHJjfCgAdwALCBYoFhS46FYJKgRuYDhyYbg9BrAUOAhqQQA3cjhqKAl6lnx54ZD7RyhcBcZnBSVw%20UVxVKiePV4QYSdrllut7jIerQYguZ6UAB0YPcnhC%20UERVK5WgACZwgBVCp3FjiOC4KBgTLcJpKKDAFLlNpsYbjPqDYb0SC4OASdabHZ7A5HE4Lc5pK43Ahgh5QJ5KWhJci2Yh2N7lHh8b4Cv4EAFAkF3cFQtweEBwmII4plLEAZgxWNplLg1KaLGAXAw9VVgL2s2gwH6szJgzJ4AmHygACI2hZoF1rMBA9tdvtDsc5rzghcfoLNSKxS8ZXKPorLr9-oDgeFJX5heJtcAYXrgvkgA)

The answer was to add a second type parameter on the method

```
interface Getter<T extends SimpleObject = SimpleObject> {
  getBody<T1 = T>(): T1
}
```